# decrypting cypher value in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net web site with connection string in external config file like this:

and external file looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData>
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue> some long string here</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

I want to decrypt it. Please suggest me how to do it ?

Comment: Is this really ambiguous? "I want to decrypt it. Please suggest me how to do it ?" seems pretty direct to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have access to the machine where that file is originating from, checkout this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)